# Добавить анимацию скрытию меню навигации?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Наткнулся в сети на код скрытия меню при прокрутке вниз и отображении при прокрутке наверх

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var header = $(".header"); // Меню
  var scrollPrev = 0 // Предыдущее значение скролла

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop(); // Высота скролла в px
    var firstScrollUp = false; // Параметр начала сколла вверх
    var firstScrollDown = false; // Параметр начала сколла вниз

    // Если скроллим
    if ( scrolled > 0 ) {
      // Если текущее значение скролла > предыдущего, т.е. скроллим вниз
      if ( scrolled > scrollPrev ) {
        firstScrollUp = false; // Обнуляем параметр начала скролла вверх
        // Если меню видно
        if ( scrolled < header.height() + header.offset().top ) {
          // Если только начали скроллить вниз
          if ( firstScrollDown === false ) {
            var topPosition = header.offset().top; // Фиксируем текущую позицию меню
            header.css({
              "top": topPosition + "px"
            });
            firstScrollDown = true;
          }
          // Позиционируем меню абсолютно
          header.css({
            "position": "absolute"
          });
        // Если меню НЕ видно
        } else {
          // Позиционируем меню фиксированно вне экрана
          header.css({
            "position": "fixed",
            "top": "-" + header.height() + "px"
          });
        }

      // Если текущее значение скролла < предыдущего, т.е. скроллим вверх
      } else {
        firstScrollDown = false; // Обнуляем параметр начала скролла вниз
        // Если меню не видно
        if ( scrolled > header.offset().top ) {
          // Если только начали скроллить вверх
          if ( firstScrollUp === false ) {
            var topPosition = header.offset().top; // Фиксируем текущую позицию меню
            header.css({
              "top": topPosition + "px"
            });
            firstScrollUp = true;
          }
          // Позиционируем меню абсолютно
          header.css({
            "position": "absolute"
          });
        } else {
          // Убираем все стили
          header.removeAttr("style");
        }
      }
      // Присваеваем текущее значение скролла предыдущему
      scrollPrev = scrolled;
    }   
  });           
});
```

Все отлично, но очень не хватает анимации при **появлении** меню. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что и куда нужно добавить в код, чтобы получить анимацию?

Comment: О какой анимации идет речь?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте добавить в стили header-а

```
transition: top 1s;
```

А вообще слишком громоздкое решение, для такой задачи

Comment: Там ещё position меняется, так что не уверен, что сработает...